# How to create sequence with maximum row value of a column in HSQL DB?

Tags: plsql, hsqldb

I need to create a sequence that starts from the maximum row value of column in HSQL. Is there any procedure we can right?

CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1  => Works fine

instead if I give like this 
CREATE SEQUENCE seq START WITH SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEST INCREMENT BY 1

shows error:unexpected token: SELECT / Error Code: -5581 / State: 42581

Comment: Why do you have Liquibase tag if your are not creating this with liquibase

Comment: Actually after knowing the query I have to create it in liquibase too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question properly, but in H2 you can use

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ START WITH 9223372036854775807 INCREMENT BY -1
```

It will return values 9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775806, 9223372036854775805, …

In HSQLDB you can use the very similar

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ START WITH 2147483647 INCREMENT BY -1
```

For columns that can't hold such large values the initial value should be decreased.

If you have a some table with existing values and want to find the largest of them and use it as a start value of the sequence, in H2 you can use a subquery directly:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ START WITH (SELECT MAX(columnName) FROM tableName)
```

You may want to add 1 to result of the query.
I don't know how to do that in HSQLDB only with SQL.

Maybe you mean something else, you definitely should edit your question and provide more details.